# Copying contents of one Word Document into another Document with different names

Tags: ms-word

I have Word 2003. I basically have over 100 documents with contents pertaining to a specific unit of a process, say Process 1. I have four other areas with different names, but the content will stay the same. How do I copy multiple contents from the first set of documents to the remaining 3 without changing the name?

There are two tables in the document, I only want to copy the second table from the first set of documents to each of the other documents. The first table has the file name and other info in it that needs to stay unique to that document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have thousands of these that will need to be copied over eventually, and doing it manually would pretty much kill me.

Thank you,

David at Work

Comment: Do you want to do this with programming? If not, if your question is just about how to use Word as a power user to get your result http://www.superuser.com is a better place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the documents are .doc binary files (since you say Word 2003).

Given this, your 2 most feasible options are to do something from within Word (eg macro or add-in), or automate Word.